# getBounds vs getBounds2D

Tags: java, awt

While reading the Java documentation on a Polygon, i discovered there is a `getBounds` method and a `getBounds2D` method. It was noted that the first one was less accurate than the second one.

I was wondering what exactly is meant by 'less accurate'? Does `getBounds` return a false value or is it about 256 vs 256.3 (example)? Or is it something completely different?

Thanks for any enlightenment,

Samuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getBounds` returns a [Rectangle](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), composed of integers, but `getBounds2D` returns a [Rectangle2D](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html), which is composed of floating point numbers, so greater precision is possible.

For `Polygon`, it shouldn't make a difference, because all of a `Polygon`'s points are integer-based, but for the more general `Shape`, which `Polygon` implements, it can matter.

Comment: Is there some way of getting a "getOuterShape" that returns a path of the smallest area that contains the full shape?